# Create automation to add membership for all in group

Tags: civimember, scheduled-job

I'm looking for a way to have Civi take all the people in a group and sign them up for a membership of a specific type, then remove them from the group. My hunch is that this should be done in scheduled jobs, but I have 0 familiarity with API and I have no idea how to write it.
For background, I'm using the integration with Ninja Forms, which doesn't appear to have a way to create or update memberships automatically. I can get it to add someone to a group after filling out a form, so I'm hoping there's a way to automate the workflow within Civi to get them from the group to the membership.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to CiviCRM SE.

You can use [Civi Rules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension, and create a rule with

1. trigger > 'Contact is Added to the Group'
2. Condition > Group = ABC
3. Action > Add membership

HTH

Pradeep